# Optimizing performance react-native component containing an image

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I have a component in my app that uses an image as a background. The component is a chat screen where users can view previous messages and send new ones. The component is connected to redux store. The component looks like this at a high level

```
// Chat screen
<Image>
  <Messages />
  <TextInput />
</Image>
```

The chat screen component will be re-rendered every time user types anything. Sometimes, users have reported a lag in typing and seeing the typed character on screen. I am thinking if it is due to the fact that `Image` is also re-rendered every time user types something and if it would make sense to extract the `Messages` and `TextInput` into a separate component and connect that to the redux store such that the `Image` is not re-rendered when user is typing.

I don't want to make this change if it is not going to affect the performance and I don't have a sure shot way to measuring if that change has affected the performance as the lag is very intermittent.

Let me know if you think this would affect the performance of the component.

Answer (score 1):

Using an image as a background can make performance issue, especially on Android. Use minified images as a background. Also, Try to capsulate the state change to the `TextInput` component by making a wrapper for it. It's a good idea to use `FlatList` for `Messages` component too.

Comment: hi @Meysam Thanks for your answer but it is not exactly what I was asking for. What I wanted to know is that when react-native re-renders a component, does having an `Image` in that component degrades the performance even though the image hasn't changed at all or is react-native able to figure out that the `Image` has not changed and doesn't re-render it and hence wouldn't affect performance even if I were to extract it out of the component.